# The Fastest method to find element in JSON (Python)

Tags: python, json

I have Json:

```
[
 {
  "name":"Apple",
  "price":2,
  "have":0,
  "max":36
 },
 {
  "name":"Pineapple",
  "price":5,
  "have":6,
  "max":17
 }
]
```

I need the fastest function, that receives name, and sends price. For example for print(jsonname("Apple")) is 2.

P.S. Please do not post Loop answers, I know them. I need fast methods and names of methods

Comment: What have you attempted so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: No, the methods. that I know are slow. So I need fastest method

Comment: @NurislomTuraev looks like you did not try anything

Comment: @NurislomTuraev Be respective to others. Everyone is trying to help you but you have to show some effort that you made. SO is not a code writing service. Try googling before you ask question and last but not least always post your code

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I didn't find anything about speed of parsing json. So I want to ask it here. Do you have something against to this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here’s an easy way to do it:

```
def function(json_object, name):
    for dict in json_object:
        if dict['name'] == name:
            return dict['price']
```

If you are sure that there are no duplicate names, an even more effective (and *pythonic*) way to do it is to use list comprehensions:

```
def function(json_object, name):
        return [obj for obj in json_object if obj['name']==name][0]['price']
```

Comment: List comprehensions is always faster than a for loop in Python. You can read more on the topic if you wish.

Comment: @Y2H list comprehensions always clean, fast and one liner. Good answer

Comment: -1, list comprehension does not automatically make it more pythonic or faster, particularly when you misuse them as you have. In your loop example, you return as soon as you find a matching value, whereas in your list comprehension, you not only create an additional unnecessary list before returning, but worse, you must evaluate on the entire list before throwing it away and just picking the first match.

Comment: @Y2H are you serious? With the first method, if the first element of `json_object` matches `name`, you return immediately. With the second method, you return only after checking every element of `json_object`, which is substantial on large lists. I tested it myself, and worst case (search which matches the last element in `json_object`), the loop takes as long as the comprehension. Best case, where the search matches the first element, outperforms the comprehension... dramatically. Take another look at what your code actually does.

Answer (score 8):

```
from json import loads

json = """[
 {
  "name":"Apple",
  "price":2,
  "have":0,
  "max":36
 },
 {
  "name":"Pineapple",
  "price":5,
  "have":6,
  "max":17
 }
]"""

parsedJson = loads (json)

def jsonname (name):
    for entry in parsedJson:
        if name == entry ['name']:
            return entry ['price']
```